# What's going on with Crucible?

Tags: xml, commit

I'm using Crucible to create a review of a xml file I commited in Git.  When I try to look at the file, I get:

> New Version: Download revision [Long name of file that i supposedly revised]

I didn't revise the xml file, so why is it doing this?